# Solve for $a, m$, given $10a^2=3m+2$, $9a^4=m^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is an algebra question (Q47.3) from Stanford problem book. I need to solve for $a, m$.

\begin{align} 10a^2&=3m+2\\ 9a^4&=m^2\end{align}

When I substitute $a^4=m^2/9$, or $a^2=m/3$, I do not get the desired answer as when I substitute $a^2=(3m+2)/10$.

Something I'm missing?

Comment: Let show all your work here.

Comment: The answer is $19m^2 - 108m - 36 = 0$.

Comment: $10(m/3) = 3m+2$ gives the answer $m=6$, which is wrong.

Comment: note that $a^4=m^2/9\implies a^2=|m|/9$

Comment: You are forgetting that $a^2$ might be $-\frac m3$....

Comment: Wy is $m= 6$ wrong?

Comment: "The answer is 19m2−108m−36=0"  That's not an answer the to question.  That may be a true statement but it doesn't tell us what $m$ or $a$ is. If $m=6$ then that statement is true. And if $m=\frac {-6}{19}$ that that statement is also true.

Comment: @AndrewYeeHinChan Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You can't go from $9a^4=m^2$ to $3a^2=m$, as you do, unless you know that $m\ge0$. Indeed, you're losing the negative solution.

It's not necessary, though, to extract square roots: if $a^2=(3m+2)/10$, then
$$
\frac{m^2}{9}=\left(\frac{3m+2}{10}\right)^{\!2}
$$
that simplifies to
$$
100m^2=81m^2+108m+36
$$
or
$$
19m^2-108m-36=0
$$
leading to
$$
m=\frac{54\pm60}{19}
$$
that is,
$$
m=-\frac{6}{19}\qquad\text{or}\qquad m=6
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: we get $$a^2=\frac{3m+2}{10}$$ so $$a^4=\left(\frac{3m+2}{10}\right)^2$$ so we have $$\frac{m^2}{9}=\left(\frac{3m+2}{10}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it:

$9a^4 = m^2$ so $a^2 = \frac {|m|}3$

And so $10a^2 = \frac {10|m|}3= 3m + 2$ so

$10|m| - 9m = 6$

If $m \ge 0$ then $m = 6$.

If $m < 0$ then $-19m = 6$ and $m = -\frac {6}{19}$.

$10a^2 = 20$ and $a = \pm \sqrt 2$ or $10a^2 = -\frac {18}{19} + 2 = 1\frac 1{19}=\frac {20}{19}$ and $a = \pm \sqrt{\frac 2{19}}$

...

I guess the way your book choose so solve it was

$a^2 = \frac {3m+2}{10}$ and

$a^4 = \frac {m^2}9$ so

$(\frac {m^2}9) =(\frac {3m+2}{10})^2 $

so $100m^2 - 9(3m + 2)^2 = 0$

$100m^2 - 9(9m^2 + 12m + 4)=0$

$100m^2 - 81m^2 - 108m - 36 = 0$

$19m^2 - 108m - 36 =0$.

That is *not* the final solution.

So $m = \frac {108 \pm \sqrt{108^2 + 4*36*19}}{38} = \{6; -\frac 6{19}\}$.

So $10a^2 = \{20, 1\frac 1{19}\}$ as $a = \{\pm \sqrt{\frac 2{19}},\pm \sqrt 2\}$